# How to programmatically read live bluetooth heart rate from Polar H10 chest strap

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I want my iOS swift software to read live bluetooth heart rate directly from my Polar H10 chest strap.

Can't find data format of Polar's H10 chest strap, though.

I'm using Swift Corebluetooth.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site; "*I want...*" isn't a question. Show us what code you've written so far as a [mre], including a succinct explanation as to where *specifically* in that attempt you're getting stuck. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Polar have an open source SDK that contains Android and iOS examples for connecting to their different sensors. You can find the SDK here:-

https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk